# Context for type of fields Referance

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have a question which has no relation to this video content at all.
I want to make a context of field of type reference
The field in module quality_control of oca (odoo 12)
The field is

`( object_id = fields.Reference(string='Reference', selection=lambda self: self.object_selection_values(), readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, ondelete="set null"))`

We tried with :

`<field name="context">{'default_object_id': 'mrp.production', active_id}</field>`

but we had an error.
If you have any comment on this it would be great.
Thank You.

Comment: I experiment with a variety of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're looking for this or not :

```
<field name="partner_id" widget="res_partner_many2one"
domain="[('customer','=',True)]" context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1, 'show_vat':True}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>
```

here in xml you can specify the context data and later use the same in python.